# Update password from database using JavaServlet

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

Hello, im working on a project in the university, and im stuck on an error. 
Im working on a mypage feature, where you can update your old password, when you are looged in. The problem is that ChangepasswordServlet is not doing what it is supposed to do.

Here you can see my servlet, the problem is probably somewhere in the IF sentence. (Manager=Entitymanager)

```
@WebServlet(name = "ChangePasswordServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ChangePassword"})
public class ChangePasswordServlet extends HttpServlet {

@EJB
UserManagerLocal manager;

private void changePassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String loggedInUsersUsername = request.getRemoteUser();

    /* PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter(); */


    User userFromTheDB = manager.getUser(loggedInUsersUsername);
    String oldPasswordFromDB = userFromTheDB.getPassword();
    String oldPasswordFromForm = (String) request.getAttribute("theOldPW");
 ;
    String newPasswordFromForm = (String) request.getAttribute("theNewPW");
    String newPasswordToCheckFromForm = (String) request.getAttribute("theNewPWCheck");


    try {
        if (oldPasswordFromDB.toLowerCase().equals(oldPasswordFromForm.toLowerCase()) && newPasswordFromForm.toLowerCase().equals(newPasswordToCheckFromForm.toLowerCase())) {

            userFromTheDB.setPassword(newPasswordFromForm);
            manager.updateUser(userFromTheDB);
            response.sendRedirect("/Slit/MyPage/PasswordSucsess.jsp");

        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("Slit/Error/error.jsp");
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException en) {
        PrintWriter print = response.getWriter();
        print.println("nullpointeryes");
        print.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    changePassword(request, response);
}

    @Override
    protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        changePassword(request, response);
    }
```

so

Here is my JSP with the form

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<head>
<title>Her kan du endre ditt nåværende passord</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="/Slit/Templates/CSS/MainPageTemplate.css">
</head>
<body>
<title>Slit</title>
<div>
<div class="form">
    <form method="post" action="/Slit/ChangePassword">
        <input type="Password" name="theOldPW" placeholder="Gammelt 
Password"/>

        <input type="Password" name ="theNewPW" placeholder="Nytt 
Password"/>

        <input type="Password" name ="theNewPWCheck" placeholder=" Nytt 
Password på nytt"/>

    <input type="submit" name="ByttePassord" value="Trykk her for å bytte 
passord!"/>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>

</head>
<body>

</body>
```

So im getting nullpointer after i have filled in the form with the old and the new password.

If im running the code now, im getting the "nullpointeryes" error.
Edit:
This is the console error after filling in the form:

```
12:39:37,194 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) Hibernate: select 
user0_.username as username2_3_0_, user0_.fName as fName3_3_0_, user0_.lName 
as lName4_3_0_, user0_.password as password5_3_0_, user0_.DTYPE as 
DTYPE1_3_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.username=?
```

Thanks for any answers

Comment: The `catch` block that contains `nullpointeryes` really isn't helping you here.  The exception that gets thrown will contain information about which line the `NullPointerException` occurred on, yet you do nothing with this exception.  At the very least, write out the stacktrace, using `en.printStackTrace();`.  That will tell you what line of your code the exception occurred on, and it will be then over to you to figure out which of your variables is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours i figured that i used get.attribute instead of parameter :/

```
String newPasswordFromForm = (String) request.getParameter("theNewPW");
String newPasswordToCheckFromForm = (String) 
request.Paramter("theNewPWCheck");
```